# Sendgrid not delivering mails to users with @email.com extensions. What could be the issue?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

An example like example@email.com.

I wanted to use send-grid to send bulk emails but users with such email extensions cannot be delivered to their inbox. Also not that the user example@email.com can send me mails. Kindly help me figure out given that i have integrated send-grid bulk emails with my laravel project. At times the user receives emails and at times they don't.